# AddThis sharing tool in magento1.9 doesn't shows custom event in my GA

Tags: google-analytics, magento-1.9, addthis

In my magento site, I have implemented GA via GTM.

I used "**AddThis** sharing tool" magento extension and configured to track the shares in my GA account attached but I noticed that even if I am sharing, there is no custom events in GA.

Rather it is getting reflected under AddThis account.

Can anyone help me in this?

Answer (score 0):

While searching for a solution, I found that AddThis team do not support this feature.

Reference: http://www.addthis.com/academy/integrating-with-google-analytics/

NOTE the line: If you have Google Universal Analytics on your page AddThis will automatically send share events without any additional configuration, unless you’ve added the Google Analytics (GA) code via Google Tag Manager (GTM). We’re working on adding support for sending events when the GA code has been added using GTM